# JSON.serialize got cycle detected error

Tags: apex, json

I am getting the

> Cycle detected. Multiple references to ...

error when executing the below line:

```
System.debug(JSON.serialize(sopAssets));
```

I tried to search for this error but currently has no clue why this is happening. And the stack trace went all the way into system code.

I tried to debug the object out but it is kind of huge so system.debug only returns a very small amount of it which doesn't really give much information.

May I know the possible cause of this error so I can start thinking about it?

Comment: Try to debug it in IDEA. Debug there is not truncated. Possibly, it will help you to detect the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you have an object that directly or indirectly refers to itself. Here's a quick demonstration:

```
Set<Object> v = new Set<Object>();
v.add(v);
JSON.serialize(v);
```

Here, we add the Set to itself, then when we try to serialize it, this results in the same exception.

Note that this exception be caused by a nested cyclic structure, such as:

```
Set<Object> v = new Set<Object>(), w = new Set<Object>();
w.add(v);
v.add(w);
JSON.serialize(v);
```

This cyclic structure can occur for any kind of object that can refer to other objects that can contain objects, including some types of `List`, `Set`, `Map`, and any user class that refers to one of the previously mentioned types or any other class.

One final example to demonstrate a cyclic object reference using a class:

```
class Wrapper {
  Wrapper parent;
}
Wrapper root = new Wrapper();
root.parent = root;
JSON.serialize(root);
```

Debugging might be hard if all you have is the data structure. You'll want to walk backwards from where the error is thrown, and follow it back to where you're building the data. As I've demonstrated above, You can only get this error with collections and non-primitives, so things like `Boolean` or `Integer` values are not the cause.

It sounds like you're generating a hierarchal organization of assets, and one of those assets has a parent asset that refers to a child asset, creating this cyclic loop. If you're using a custom class, look for assignments (`=`). If it's a standard collection type, look for the various manipulation methods: `add`, `addAll`, `put`, and `putAll`. Your culprit will likely be very near one of these four methods.